# BarChart without axes neglects the last zero of a list

Tags: plotting

Creating a BarChart with {1, 2, 3, 0} as

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 0}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

gives me only the first three bars, a chart identical to just

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

1. Is this an intended behaviour or a bug?
2. (Originally I asked for a workaround. I think I can just use `Axes` instead of `Frame`. Let me ask this instead for the sake of knowledge.) What to do if I need `Frame` but not `Axes`?

I'm using Mathematica 9.

Comment: is that cheating? `BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 0}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0]], 
 Frame -> True]`. There must be a smarter way -

Comment: Your workaround is great. I think you have answered Question 2! Could you please post it as an answer so I can mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot answer why this is happening. Intuitively, I interpret `BarChart` as a chart with no "real", scaled, x-axis. Thus, a frame does not really make a lot of sense to me (with ticks)...

Nevertheless, you could use the following work-around to make the axis "vanish":

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 0}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0]], Frame -> True]
```

This will keep the last (zero) bar:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Now I'll just customise the chart further, like [this](http://xxx.fivefourseven.com/stack-5.png).

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's not there? I get this picture:

[image]

What appears to be nothingness attached on the end is really a bar of height zero. You can see this more clearly if you do it in 3D

```
BarChart3D[{1, 2, 3, 0}]
```

which gives

[image]

Now you can see the stump of the zero bar. Another way to see it would be:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 0}, LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#, Above] &)]
```

[image]

which labels things with the number.

Comment: Thank you. I just updated my question a bit. It seems the option `Axes -> False` causes the last zero to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do:

```
GraphicsRow[BarChart[#, AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}] & /@ {{1, 2, 3, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Just to be sure

Comment: Thank you. Now I have updated my question. With `Axes` set to `False`, the last zero really disappears.